# How to use RequestExecutionLevel inside IF THEN block

Tags: nsis

I have nsis package that consist of 3 items:
1. .Net 4.0 setup
2. C++ redistr
3. My App

My installer is always silent. In this package I check installed version of .Net and C++ and install from my package if I have bigger, but if user have correct version of net and c++, my package just export my app to temp folder and run it.

To install .net or c++ user must has admin rigths, but to run my app it is not needed. I don`t want always request admin rigths with **RequestExecutionLevel admin**

It is possible some how implement such logic in package:

```
IF (user_has_net != true || user_has_c++ != true) {
   RequestExecutionLevel admin
} else {
   RequestExecutionLevel user 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`RequestExecutionLevel`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/RequestExecutionLevel) property is set for your installer at compile time and is embedded in the installers manifest. It can't be set at runtime.

The best workaround I can think of in your case would be to embed another installer that handles the C++ runtime libraries and .Net. Then that installer can have `RequestExecutionLevel` set to `admin` and be extracted and executed by your primary installer as needed.

Something like this should work.

```
IF (user_has_net != true || user_has_c++ != true) {
  SetOutPath "$TEMP"
  File "OtherInstaller.exe"
  ExecWait "$TEMP\OtherInstaller.exe"
}
```

Comment: You are right, so simple and elegant solution. Thank you